# How to present UIPopoverController in ios8 on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, xcode6, uipopovercontroller

In ios7, I can present popovercontroller without any problem on iPad, but in `ios8 it doesn't work`. I have searched for solutions in Google and here, but none works. This is the code I change for ios8:

```
privateChat = [[PrivateChatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrivateChatViewController" bundle:nil];
privateChat.delegate = self;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:privateChat];
[popoverController setDelegate:self];
//work in ios7
//[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(privateChat.view.frame.size.width,privateChat.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
//[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.frame inView:self.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

//Edit for ios8, but not work

```
privateChat.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake([privateChat.view.superview superview].frame.size.width,[privateChat.view.superview superview].frame.size.height) ;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize: privateChat.preferredContentSize animated:YES];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.frame inView:[self.view.superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
});
```

It doesn't work in ios8 and there is no crash too. What should I change or add to make it work ?

Comment: There is some difference in your call, in first on you are showing popover on `self.superview` and in second one `self.view.superview`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that works perfectly in my project(iPad ios8 objective-c),
(i faced same issue and bellow code solved my issue.)
you should try this,

```
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        self.popover.delegate=self;
        CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[_btnimgProfilePic frame] fromView:[_btnimgProfilePic superview]];

        popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100) ;
        popoverRect.origin.x = popoverRect.origin.x;

        // this works properly in my project

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{
                [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];
                            });
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it again with your code, and I will tell if it works.